# Python 3.7 - how to index console commands to use as a reference

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, command-line

I'm learning Python and stuck with below task thus appreciate some help. (version 3.7)

Task: Record console inputs into a file - assign an ID to it to be able to delete based on the ID. Be able to list it.

Full code below for reference - yet I struggle with assigning an index to the user input and delete it based on that ID. I was advised that it is possible relying on `sys.argv` - yet I kinda feel this is rather expecting a dictionary usage (which I am not familiar with yet).

I was trying to add a number prior to the user input in the file (so the text file would look like `001. *user input*,\n 002. *user input*`, etc), thus all lines shall get numbered. 
Based on that when the user enters a certain number(=certain line) to be deleted the script should delete the given line. Yet I failed to look up and make python understand the number reference at the beginning of the line (some sort of search function would work I assume). 
Can I tell the script to delete based online reference?

edit: given that the program shuts down after every entry `len(sys.argv)` will remain 1. A possible solution could be -if I don't shut it down- to refer to the index number to delete certain line based on the reference. But how do I feed again the variable/index number after restarting the program? The index will start again from 1 (as 0 reserved) and will disregard the number of lines already in the text.

Thanks in advance!

```
import sys

menu = input("What o you want to do?\n  add new idea(1)\n delete an idea(2)\n list all ideas(3)")
if menu == "1":
    myfile = open("ideabank.txt", 'a+', encoding = 'utf-8')
    newidea = input("What is your new idea?:")
    print('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
    myfile.write(newidea)
    myfile.write("\n")
    myfile.close()


elif menu == "2":
    print("delete")

else:
    myfile = open("ideabank.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
    for line in myfile:
        print(line, end="")
    myfile.close()
```

Comment: `sys.argv` seems like a red herring here. I would just read the file in, filter out the victim line, then write back out the rest of the lines.

Comment: afaik Python 3.7 is quite new and not all other packages support it yet, so I'm not sure if you should use it as a beginner. 3.6.5 might be good enough.

Comment: AKX - if I understand you correctly you would load the full test into a list, slice by lines. I could print the # of the element within the list to give a reference point to the user and make the deletion based on that.
Wouldn't it create resource issues with a bigger file?

Comment: JHBonarius - thanks for the advice! indeed the reco is to work with 3.6 but i read that all packages are backward compatible as of 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myfile = open("ideabank.txt", 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8')
    newidea = input("Which line you want to delete:")
    data = myfile.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(data))
        if i != int(newidea):
           myfile.write(data[i])
           myfile.write("\n") 

myfile.close()
```

Comment: Nihal -  w+ shall wipe all previous entries. r+ works to some extent - but it doesn't delete the previous entries, but keeps the lines dividable by the user input (I given 2, and every 2nd lines were kept)

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the question for any future possible check.
The solution I used was to use list in lists. Thus the index of the element was the ordering and the tasks and the completion status was the 0 and 1 elements of the list-in-lists.